In which direction should ceiling drywall be hung on furring strips below joists?
Ceiling joist run North/South. Attached to these are evenly spaced boards running East/West the full distance of the room.  Which direction do I hang my ceiling drywall?

Whichever way you want to, as it does not make that big of a difference, but the normal approach with battens (those evenly spaced boards running East/West) is to put the long direction of the drywall sheets perpendicular to the battens.

Generally you hang ceiling drywall perpendicular to the mounting members. This isn't always critical, but some drywall has a strength axis that must be observed. It's also easier, since fitting sheets to parallel framing can be difficult--framing is rarely perfect. What's above the mounting members is completely irrelevant.
